# Wrong results when assigning to int array in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main(){
    int v[5];
    int a[5][5];
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        v[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            a[i][j] = 0;
            cout << "A[" << i << ", " << j << "] = " << endl;
            cin >> a[i][j];
            v[i] = v[i] + a[i][j];
        }   
        v[i] = v[i] / 5;
    }   

    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        cout << "v[" << i << "] = " << v[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

When I remove the `v[i] = 0` line just under the first loop the code runs but returns very large numbers. I don't understand how this is happening. Grateful for any help.

Edit: thanks you for all the replies. I think I understand why I got downvotes. To clarify, this is for a beginners course and we were given the bare-bones of the language mostly to train logic. The question itself is pretty nonsensical as it asks us to declare the array as a int despite the fact that the answer is distorted by integer division.

Comment: If you remove a variables initialization, the variable will be uninitialized.

Comment: ... and lead to _undefined behavior_.

Comment: `int v[5]{};` if you want to initialise it at declaration time.

Comment: `v[i] = v[i] + a[i][j];` is [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) since you never initialized the values in `v`, so reading them (`v[i]`) is reading an indeterminate value. Variable (and array) values are *not* automatically `0` - they are *undefined* and you are not allowed to read them.

Comment: Did you account for integer division:  `v[i] = v[i] / 5;`?

Comment: This code doesn't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line. Not to mention that `std::cout` and `std::cin` are tied, so reading input through `std::cin` will flush `std::cout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializing a value in c++ like `int v[5];` just reserves space. It does nothing to initialize the values to 0 or something. Anything could be in those five indices. Whatever happens to be in that address space.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of garbage values in your array. Your array has a size of 5 but you try to iterate until the 30th value. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you remove `v[i]=0`, that makes `v[I]=` undefined, and that is what makes `v[I]` look like really long numbers. Try to initialize every variable which you will use for successive sum.